# How to compare two columns both with list of strings and create a new column with unique items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns both with list of strings. Basically one column `df['products']` which are in all capitals. The other column is product description `df['desc']`.

I want to check what all items in `df['products']` are present in `df['desc']` and make a new column out of it.

I tried the following code:

```
df['uniq'] = df.apply(lambda x : [i for i in x['products'] if i.lower() in x['desc']])
```

I checked the other similar questions and built the above code, but it's not working.

The data looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need add `axis=1` if need check per rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'products':[['A','B'],['D','C']],
                   'desc':[['a', 'c'],['c', 'e']]})

df['uniq'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x['products'] if i.lower() in x['desc']], axis=1)
print (df)
     desc products uniq
0  [a, c]   [A, B]  [A]
1  [c, e]   [D, C]  [C]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `apply()` when you don't absolutely need to.  It's slow.

Instead, do it the vectorized way:

```
desc_upper = df.desc.str.upper()
matches = df.products.isin(desc_upper)
result = df.products[matches]
```